# How to use a glm::mat4 in a glRotatef

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, opengl-compat

In modern OpenGL I would translate, rotate, scale, etc.  like this:

```
m_cart.orientation = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(m_cart.T, m_cart.N, m_cart.B));

modelViewMatrixStack.Push();
    modelViewMatrixStack.Translate(m_cart.position);
    modelViewMatrixStack *= m_cart.orientation;
    modelViewMatrixStack.Scale(0.01f);
    m_cart.Render();
modelViewMatrixStack.Pop();
```

But now for reasons outside my control I have to use some old OpenGL and I've changed the code to something like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(m_cart.position.x, m_cart.position.y, m_cart.position.z);
    glScalef(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
    m_cart.Render();
glPopMatrix();
```

Above is pretty much equivalent but I can't figure out how I can apply the rotation using the `glm::mat4`. `glRotatef` wants an angle and floats for xyz. I've looked at [`glm::decompose´](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00204.html) to get those out of the 4x4matrix but it's not very clear.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set an arbitrary orientation with a single `glRotate`. you would need up to 3 rotations.
But it is not necessary to rotate the matrix, since you know the final orientation matrix already. Instead of calculating the parameters for [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) you can use [`glMultMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml) which can directly multiply the `m_cart.orientation` matrix to the matrix stack:

```
m_cart.orientation = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(m_cart.T, m_cart.N, m_cart.B));

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(m_cart.position.x, m_cart.position.y, m_cart.position.z);
    glMultMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(m_cart.orientation)); 
    glScalef(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
    m_cart.Render();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Perfect. `glm::value_ptr` seems to be pretty useful in reverting back to "old openGL" in other scenarios. Cheers.